# Showing set is open and path-connected

Tags: general-topology

I need to decide whether the set $E = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^4:x_1^2 + x_2^2 < 1, x_3^2 + x_4^2 > 1/4\}$ is open and path connected and prove my result. I'm fairly certain it is, but am unsure exactly how to show this. Is it simply the product of two open and path connected sets? Or is there something else to it?

Comment: Here's an easy way to show that it's an open set: consider the map $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, defined by $f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (x_1^2 + x_2^2,\, x_3^2 + x_4^2)$. It's clear that $E = f^{-1} (F)$, where 
$$
F = (-\infty, 1) \times (\tfrac14, \infty) = \bigl\{ \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^2: y_1 < 1,\, y_2 > \tfrac14 \bigr\}.
$$
You have to show that $f$ is continuous and $F$ is open.

Comment: Consider a 3d cross-section of this 4d set.  Is it open? Is it path connected?  Can you extend the result?

Comment: For path connectedness, sometimes it's useful to think "blurry" thoughts first, which will lead you to be able to write down something rigorous. The set $E$ treats the first two variables separately from the last two. Points are not too far from the origin in the $(x_1, x_2)$-plane, and they're not too close to the origin in the $(x_3, x_4)$-plane. Does this help you to write down a path between any two points in $E$?

Comment: @SammyBlack. Yes, showing that it's open isn't a huge issue here. Regarding your second comment: the fact that $E$ treats both variables separately is what lead me to believe that I can break it down in to the product of a 2-D open ball $B^2(0; 1)$ and the complement of a 2-D closed ball $B^2(0; 1/2)$. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Try to be more concrete; can you write down a path explicitly between two points in the set?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$1).\ $ In $\mathbb R^4,$ open and connected $\Rightarrow$ path-connected.

$2).\ $ Each of the sets in your question is open. (a nice proof is in the comments.)

$3).\ $ The two sets in your question have a point in common.